# ArgumentError in EnvelopesController#index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i am trying to validate that amount in Account cannot be less than the sum of amount in envelope
but i am getting this error

> You need to supply at least one validation
>     validates :total_amount_in_all_envelope_can_not_be_greater_than_account_total[image]

here is my model

```
class Envelope < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

    validates :tag, presence: true
    validates :account_id, presence: true
    validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than: 0, message: " must be greater than $0.0 "}  
    validates :total_amount_in_all_envelope_can_not_be_greater_than_account_total


    def total_amount_in_all_envelope_can_not_be_greater_than_account_total
        if 
            @account.envelopes.sum(&:amount) > @account.amount
            errors.add(:amount, "Envelope amount cannot be reater than Account total" )
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You have a typo there - `addd `.

Comment: @SebastianPalma: ah, good eye.

Answer (score 3):

When using your own methods to populate record's `errors`, the method to call is `validate`, not `validates`.

```
validate :total_amount_in_all_envelope_can_not_be_greater_than_account_total
```

Comment: it did work now, but it also seems my logic is wrong! i am getting undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @bottles: yeah, you probably should fix your logic now. And that typo.

Comment: i am unable to fix my logic.need help please. i have already tried this too but i am getting undefined method `envelopes' for nil:NilClass                                      
     if 
            @account.envelopes.sum(&:amount) > @account.amount
            errors.add(:amount, "Envelope amount cannot be greater than Account total" )
        end

Comment: @bottles: your original problem is fixed. All follow-up errors are out of scope here.